# Session sharing on JBoss within the same EAR

Tags: session, jboss, weblogic

I'm trying to migrate an application from WebLogic 11g to JBoss AS 7.1.

Our application is based on the following EAR design (with JBoss convention):

```
myapp.ear
 |--- launcher.war
 |--- app1.war
 |--- app2.war
 |--- ...
 |--- lib
```

The user connects to the `launcher` application, signs in, and then is allowed from this launcher to access `app1`, `app2` etc...

It works fine, because in the launcher we put in the session an object `User.java` (available in a jar in the lib/ folder), which is visible in all apps since WebLogic allows sharing the same session within the same EAR with the following configuration, in file `weblogic-application.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<wls:weblogic-application >
 <wls:session-descriptor>
     <wls:sharing-enabled>true</wls:sharing-enabled>
 </wls:session-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

However, I can't find any equivalent to the `sharing-enabled` flag. I managed to [disable the isolation within an EAR](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Class+Loading+in+AS7), [share the same JSESSION ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16230162/1172000) within all applications (but the session is still not shared), and people are suggesting [SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204712/1172000) which looks overkill for my application.

Is there any way to share the session, or should I redesign the whole application and put all my apps in the launcher WAR?

Thanks by advance for any help.

Comment: have you ever resolved this ?

Comment: No, this project is idle...

Comment: Thanks for the answer... If it may help you, I was able to resolve using hazelcast filter which automatically cache session datas, for an hazelcast.sessionid which is the same for all deployed apps (wars) of the servers. This is 5 min config, 1 jar file and it fixes it.

Comment: Thanks, will try it if my project comes back to life :)

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm struggling with a similar issue. Thanks in advance